# wireless network cannot be established

Tags: networking, windows-7, wireless-networking

One of our windows 7 laptop cannot connect to our wireless LAN whereas other laptops are able to connect to the same WIFI without any troubles.

When an ethernet cable is connected **and** wireless connection is turned ON, it says WPA-PSK2 signal is active with 54 mbps. The wireless adapter is getting an IP address of `10.10.10.1` and the ethernet adapter with `10.10.10.2`.

I tried to ping both addresses from the modem and there was 50 %, 75 % and 100 % packet loss to wireless adapter and ethernet adapter has no issues.

We use a special DNS addresss supplied by the ISP and the ethernet LAN internet connection is working ok. I tried to ping another computer when wireless LAN only is enabled, it couldn't ping to other computer on the network.

So there seems to be some problem with the wireless adapter and/or driver. But when I took that laptop to a different WIFI, it connected without any problems.

Comment: When dealing with network issues, you have to consider both the access point (router) and the adapter (PC). If you can connect to others wireless networks, then most likely the wireless settings on your PC are not configured correctly for *your* network.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more detail could be useful here. Specifically, what kind of router are you using? What kind of firmware on the router? Who made your wireless card? Just to be clear, is that packet loss you mentioned (50%,75%, and 100%) when your computer is plugged in via Ethernet, or is it occurring when your computer is only connected with WiFi? Have you

I doubt you've got a drive problem, considering that your ethernet works just fine and you're not reporting any symptoms traditionally associated with hard drives. The fact that the problem exists only on your network suggests that the problem has been created by some sort of conflicting settings, so I'll try and provide some guidance for resolving those.

Assuming that all your software is up-to date, try disconnecting from the network, then [deleting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252588(WS.10).aspx) it from your computer's list of remembered networks. Then try to reconnect.

If you're still having difficulty, try checking out the [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-information-appears-in-event-logs-Event-Viewer) in Windows, and see if there's anything useful there. Also, check to see if your router has logging enabled. If that's the case, see if it's reporting any exceptions when you try to connect. With only your question to go on, I can't really provide much more detail. A reinstall of Windows could be worth a try, but it's a pain, so I'd use that as a near-to-last resort.

Comment: The ethernet and wireless adapters usually do not use the same drivers.